# Problem with Win32_PhysicalMedia SerialNumber property

Tags: wmi

I wrote the following code to get the physical media serial number but in one of my computers it returns null instead.
Does anybody know what the problem is?
Thanks.

```
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMedia");
foreach( ManagementObject mo in searcher.Get() )
{
    Console.WriteLine("Serial: {0}", mo["SerialNumber"]);
}
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502812/problem-with-wmi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Serial Number is optional, defined by the manufacturer, and for your device it is either blank or unsupported by the driver.

Virtually all hard drives have a serial number, but most USB-style Flash memory sticks do not (generally a cost issue). I would imagine most unbranded CD/DVD/BD discs would also be non-serialized.

Comment: The system I use has both XP and Win7 RC1 and only has one HDD installed, in Win7 it returns the HDD serial number but in XP it returns null.

Comment: You mean that the for the same disk the serial number is returned in Windows 7 and not returned in Windows XP? In any case, use wbemtest.exe to verify that your code returns correct values - if the SerialNumber property is <null> in Windows XP there is not much you can do about it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code I used, the serial number somehow is returned raw with each pair of chars reversed (strange) and using Win32_PhysicalMedia gave different results if I ran the code as a user or an Administrator(more strange) - Windows 7 Ultimate, VS 2008 using VB only:

```
Function GetHDSerial() As String
    Dim strHDSerial As String = String.Empty
    Dim index As Integer = 0
    Dim Data As String
    Dim Data2 As String
    Dim ndx As Integer

    Dim query As New SelectQuery("Win32_DiskDrive")
    Dim search As New ManagementObjectSearcher(query)
    Dim info As ManagementObject
    Try
        For Each info In search.Get()
            Data = info("SerialNumber")
            Data2 = ""
            For ndx = 1 To Data.Length - 1 Step 2
                Data2 = Data2 & Chr(Val("&H" & Mid(Data, ndx, 2)))
            Next ndx
            Data = String.Empty
            For ndx = 1 To Data2.Length - 1 Step 2
                Data = Data & Mid(Data2, ndx + 1, 1) & Mid(Data2, ndx, 1)
            Next
            Data2 = Data
            If Len(Data) < 8 Then Data2 = "00000000" 'some drives have no s/n
            Data2 = Replace(Data2, " ", "") ' some drives pad spaces in the s/n
            'forget removeable drives
            If InStr(info("MediaType").ToString, "Fixed", CompareMethod.Text) > 0 Then
               strHDSerial = strHDSerial & "Drive " & index.ToString & " SN: " & Data2 & vbCrLf
               index += 1
            End If
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        strHDSerial = "Error retrieving SN for Drive " 
        msgbox(index.ToString)
    End Try
    Return strHDSerial
End Function
```